# How to access xsi:type attribute of a xs:anySimpleType element in xjc generated class?

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, xjc

I need to marshal and unmarshal XMLs that contains structures like this:

```
<Parameter>
    <Name>Country</Name>
    <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">Uruguay</Value>
</Parameter>
```

that are defined in the following schema fragment:

```
<xs:complexType name="Parameter">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Name">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:maxLength value="256"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Value" type="xs:anySimpleType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

The generated class with xjc for the above schema is the following:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Parameter", propOrder = {
    "name",
    "value"
})
public class Parameter {

    @XmlElement(name = "Name", required = true)
    protected String name;
    @XmlElement(name = "Value", required = true)
    protected Object value;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String value) {
        this.name = value;
    }

    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Object value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

As you can see the `xsi:type` attribute in the `Value` element is not present in `Parameter` class. And I need to access it as a business requirement.

I have tried modifying the original schema like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="ParameterValue">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:anySimpleType">
            <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="Parameter">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Name">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:maxLength value="256"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Value" type="ParameterValue"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

So the `value` property in `Parameter` class is of type `ParameterValue` that contains both type and actual value. This way I have a getter for the type, but type and value are "decoupled" now. I mean when marshaling, the type have to be set manually and it is not inferred from value.

Is there a better way to deal with anySimpleType elements?

Comment: xsi:type is used implicitly when using polymorphic values in your XML documents. It acts as a hint for a parser to map a value to a specific in this case Java type. After the type conversion has been done during marshalling it's regarded as needless and that's the reason why you don't see it in your Java class. I don't know your business case and can't imagine what information you want to derive from the attribute, so I can't further help here.